# This method is only available in managed mode error by sort

Tags: android, sorting, realm

I have LinkedHashSet and I want to transfer to created RealmList and sort datas.

```
    final LinkedHashSet<Message> batchSelected = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public LinkedHashSet<Message> getSelectedItems() {
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(batchSelected);
    }

    public void toggleSelection(Message message) {

        if (!batchSelected.remove(message)) {
            batchSelected.add(message);
        }
    }

    public void clearSelection() {
        batchSelected.clear();
    }
```

This function is provide that transfer datas from batchSelected to selectedMessages. It is working if not added sort function. Otherwise it prints an error.

How can I sort messages by id and how can I go into managed mode?

```
    public RealmList<Message> getSelectedMessages() {

    RealmList<Message> selectedMessages = new RealmList<>();
    selectedMessages.addAll(batchSelected);
    selectedMessages.sort("id", Sort.ASCENDING);

    return selectedMessages;
   }
```

Error log:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.android.android.debug, PID: 19653
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is only available
>   in managed mode. at io.realm.RealmList.sort(RealmList.java:511) at
>   com.android.android.Model.getSelectedMessages(Model.java:146)
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RealmList selectedMessages = new RealmList<>();

This is unmanaged RealmList, which basically works like an ArrayList.

If this is what you want, then Realm cannot sort it as it has nothing to do with Realm, but following would work:

```
Collections.sort(selectedMessages, new Comparator<Message>() { ...
```

---

However, if you want to have a managed RealmList, that's only possible if you retrieve a `RealmList` field from a managed `RealmObject` obtained from Realm.

```
Obj obj = realm.where(Obj.class).findFirst(); // managed RealmObject
RealmList<SomeObj> others = obj.getOthers(); // managed RealmList
```

If you want managed collection of items from Realm, then you should execute the right RealmQuery.

```
RealmResults<Message> selectedMessages = realm.where(Message)
    .in("id", batchSelectedIds)
    .sort("id", Sort.ASCENDING)
    .findAll();
```

Comment: please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760244/realm-repeating-lines-on-realm-adapter